# Union of two subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $M$. The union of $A$ and $B$ also a subset of $M$, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Union of $A$ and $B$ means the values of both $A$ and $B$ without repetition, since $A$ and $B$ are both subsets of $M$, it would imply that all values of $A$ and $B$ are also values of $M$, can you solve it now?

**Hint**: For a set $X$ to be a subset of another set $Y$, all values of X has to be present in Y

Comment: Thank you for the hint, it led to the answer.